# integral with log and exponential

Tags: integration, logarithms, exponential-function

This integral seems to complex for me and I could not find a solution. Can Laplace transform be a useful? Is anyone willing to help me? Thanks.

$\int_{0}^{\infty} (\frac{log(1+x)e^{(-x/b)}}{ax+c})dx$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I do not know if I should be able to finish but this could be a way using Feynman trick.*

Let us consider
$$I(k)=\int_0^\infty \frac{ \log (1+kx)}{a x+c}e^{-\frac{x}{b}}\,dx$$
$$I'(k)=\int_0^\infty \frac{x e^{-\frac{x}{b}}}{(k x+1) (a x+c)}\,dx$$
$$\frac{x }{(k x+1) (a x+c)}=\frac 1{a-ck}\left(\frac{1}{k x+1}-\frac{c}{a x+c} \right)$$
$$(a- ck)I'(k)=\frac{c e^{\frac{c}{a b}} }{a}\text{Ei}\left(-\frac{c}{a b}\right)-\frac{e^{\frac{1}{b k}} }{k}\text{Ei}\left(-\frac{1}{b k}\right)$$ This could be expressed in terms of the incomplete gamma function.

Going to $I(k)$ leaves us with a simple integral and a nasty one but it could be easy to perform numerical integration of it (this would be much easier to do than for the initial integral).

Comment: Thanks, it is great help! I have not think of Feynman trick before. In order to have $I(k)$, I could not take the integral of $E_i$ parts. Specifically, I could not understand the relation between $E_i$ and incomplete gamma function. Do you have any other tips on that, which will help me to conclude the solution? (If it is not a big bother) Thank you so much! @ClaudeLeibovici

Comment: @MinaKayNak. There is no solution to the problem. One possibility is to compute the integral as it is; the other one (from what I wrote) would need numerical integration of a part of an ODE.